# Removing html tags from multiple strings array in Javascript/React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am receiving some bad data for certain product items and in my react native app its creating a bug where its outputting the bold html tags unintentionally - it isn't doing this in the website as the browser will be converting the bold tags into readable bold text in the web.

I am wondering what the best way would be to check if the array contains the bold tag and filter/remove this out of the state.
Here is an example of the data I am getting back and how its currently rendering:

```
["<bold>Dish Washer</bold>", "fridge", "<bold>kettle</bold", "Oven"]

  . <bold>Dish Washer</bold>
  . Fridge
  . <bold>Kettle</bold>
  . Oven
```

I was also wondering if there is a way to possibly check which products are displaying the  tags, as it only seems to be happening with certain product descriptions.

Comment: _"I am wondering..."_ - What have you tried so far? Any attempts at all? Research? `.indexOf()` + `.replace()`, regular expression (if its really just `<bold>...</bold>`), `DOMParser()`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array map()+ string replace() for a quick and dirty fix.

something like this (or better use a regex replace):

```
["<bold>Dish Washer</bold>", "fridge", "<bold>kettle</bold>", "Oven"].map(item => item.replace('<bold>','').replace('</bold>',''))
```

But you should in fact fix the root of problem (the source of the products)

Answer (score 1):

use foreach and replace method

```js
<script>

var a = ["<bold>Dish Washer</bold>", "fridge", "<bold>kettle</bold>", "Oven"];
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
a.forEach((item) =>{
   var values=  item.replace(regex, '');
    console.log(values);***`

> strong text

`***

})
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I experimented a bit and found this solution. You can alter the regex any time to filter other values

```
const x = ["<bold>Dish Washer</bold>", "fridge", "<bold>kettle</bold", "Oven"];

const regex = /(?<=<bold>)(.*)(?=<\/bold>)/ig;

const result = x.filter(i => !regex.test(i));
```